# How to model an irregular object made of tubes?

Tags: modeling

How can I model this irregular curved torus shape that is in the back of this dolly? I know how to cut apart a torus but I think what I need is for a torus to be extruded along a curve line.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, this site works best when you ask one question at a time. I would say "How to connect a cylinder to a plane" and "How to model complex curved objects" are two separate questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects that are made out of tubes can be modelled with curve objects.

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>*> Curve> Bezier*
2. On the curve properties make the curve fill type 'full' and set the Bevel depth and resolution to increase the diameter of the tube and the smoothness of it:

[image]

The curve on the left is what it looks like after adding it and editing it's shape in edit mode. The curve on the right is after the above settings have been applied.

[image]

You can extrude this curve and edit it similarly to how you would edit a mesh, using scaling, rotating and moving to manipulate the curve handles.

If at some point you want it to be a mesh you can select the curve and choose <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>*> Mesh from Curve*

Comment: +1 The moment I saw the question, bezier curve tubing was my immediate thought. Great minds think alike.