# Join two cylinders

Tags: modeling

How can I join these two meshes in a proper way? I know I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> to join them, but how can I do so without having overlapping faces?

[image: two cylinders in solid shading mode]
[image: two cylinders in wireframe]

Comment: You'll wan't to use snapping

Comment: Not an answer to the question but this can give you some ideas on how to cu and join pieces: http://www.evermotion.org/tutorials/show/8131/8-methods-of-cutting-holes-using-blender

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off, [ask yourself](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14482/2217) if you really need those two pipes connected? In a real [hand truck](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27366/2217) those are two different pipes welded together at the joint. Joining them would actually make creating the materials and shading harder. You could just add a [weld](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15629/2217) around the joint, and you would never even know that they are separate objects (plus it would be more physically accurate).

However since you asked:
Start off by making sure the two pipes have the same vertex count.

1. Snap the end of the horizontal pipe to the center of the vertical pipe.  [image: first step: moving the pipes in to place]
2. Select the horizontal pipe, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the vertical pipe. Make sure you are looking down the horizontal pipe and then [knife Project](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html?#knife-project) to make the cut.
   [image: knife project]
3. Delete the new faces, <kbd>X</kbd> > *Faces*.
4. Join the two pipes in to one object. Then switch your view so that you are looking at the side of the horizontal pipe.
5. Snap each of the vertices from the end of the horizontal pipe to the location of the vertices in the cut made earlier.
   [image: snapping the last vertices]
6. Select all the vertices and then remove doubles, <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge by Distance*

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to go about this, you can [eyeball it and do it with some clean cuts or use a boolean modifier etc](https://vimeo.com/6757036) but why reinvent the wheel for rather simple objects when you could be finishing another part of your scene?

Go to *User Prefs* and enable the *Extra Objects* addon and you can use the *T-Joint* object. You can tweak the radius, divisions etc. There are also similar custom primitive types for pipe joints if you're doing some architectural stuff.

[image]