# Connect two cylinders at the corner of a bench seat

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, faces

I have another problem within Blender. I can't find a way to connect two cylinders at the corner of a bench seat. I have four corners to connect.

Here is a picture:
[image]

Only one of the corners is depicted. I tried selecting the two faces I want covered and making Edge/Face, however that doesn't work. I don't want to select two edges at a time and make edge/face. That's going to be tedious and will take a while.

Here is the .blend: [Blendfile](http://www.mediafire.com/download/wnd3704k8mb78s2/Connecting_two_cylinders_at_an_L_joint_for_a_seat_coushin.blend)

I'm not trying to achieve what [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27383/join-two-cylinders) asks. This is what would be an "L joint" if the cylinders' connection were to be called one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it can be achieved with [Bridge Edge Loops](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#bridge-edge-loops) function:

1. Align 'end cap' polygons at the beginnings of the desired curve. The trick is to maintain same distance from the angle point
2. Select both caps and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*
3. Tweak connection properties

[image: Caps aligned with tangent points]
[image: At the left panel properties can be found]

Comment: That answer was very helpful! It worked like a charm. Thank you!