# T-junction pipe

Tags: objects

I've just downloaded Blender and am starting it for the very first time. I am a computer programmer, not a designer. I downloaded this for a specific requirement that I have - nothing to do with programming.

I need to give a 3-d model to someone so that he can print it on his 3d printer. The design calls for a series of hollow pipes connected to each other at right angles only. Nothing fancy nor challenging from a model designer's point of view, I'm sure. Assume that it's simply two parallel tubes about 2 feet long and 6 inches apart with four tiny 6-inch pipes connecting them. The dimensions have to be exact for the inner and outer diameters.

I am not asking how it is done, nor asking for one of you to draw them.

Kindly point me to the nearest kickstart tutorial for doing something like this and I'll hopefully be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqDnLg3o9WE
Took 5 secs to google this. Have a nice day.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27383/join-two-cylinders

Comment: read [How to approach the modeling of duct work, piping, wiring](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42591/how-to-aproach-the-modeling-of-duct-work-piping-wiring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Edit -> preferences -> Addons.

Search for extra: ***Add Mesh Extra Objects***.

Go to the viewport press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select: Mesh -> ***Pipe joints***.

There are 5 pipe joints to choose from and you can customize them any way you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This will do it. Does it display the inner and outer diameter as well?

Comment: Those pipes don't have a solid wall, IDK what you mean with inner diameter.

Comment: If the joints are to be 3D printed, they need a solid wall. That can be achieved with [Solidify modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html), with Fill Rim set to "on".

Answer (score -1):

To put a solid wall you first select the object then you add a *Solidify* modifier under *Properties > Modifiers > Solidify* then adjust the thickness the way you want it and apply.