Intersecting cylinders

I need a single stl surface mesh for a cylinder tube intersecting another cylinder tube(+sphere) at 90 degrees. I managed to use the boolean modifier to get the difference, however, it is not 'cut' and there is an excess lip of the cylinder-tube inside. I have the same problem as above with the cylinder-tube + sphere intersection, where there is an excess cylinder lip inside the sphere (not seen in the image). There must be a correct way to do this. Any pointers are much appreciated.
Context, I need an stl file to run some molecular dynamics simulations. The big cylinder is a neuronal dendrite, and the smaller cylinder+sphere is a synaptic terminal.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27383/join-two-cylinders

If the boolean operation went through then you should be able to select those inner faces and delete them?
